# I've made a attendence register program and I want to save into a file which is created newly everyday, which I don't know how to in java

Tags: java

the below program takes input from teacher or anyone filling attendence using class for student names and if..else statements for taking their attendence.
I want to know of how can I save the attendece in a file which would be named as attendence's date in a specified folder.
I am new to java and I do not have knowlege on file based programs.

```
import java.util.*;
public class prr
{
    public static class stud 
    {
        String s1 = "Student 1";
        String s2 = "Student 2";
        String s3 = "Student 3";
        String s4 = "Student 4";
        String s5 = "Student 5";
        String s6 = "Student 6";
        String s7 = "Student 7";
        String s8 = "Student 8";
        String s9 = "Student 9";
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        //Date
        System.out.println("Date : "+java.time.LocalDate.now());



        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        stud stu = new stud();
        System.out.println("Name of Students : \n\n"+stu.s1+"\n"+stu.s2+"\n"+stu.s3+"\n"+stu.s4+"\n"+stu.s5+"\n"+stu.s6+"\n"+stu.s7+"\n"+stu.s8+"\n"+stu.s9);
        
        //instruction
        System.out.println("");


        //s1
        System.out.print("Is "+stu.s1+" present? ");
        String st1 = sc.nextLine();
        if(st1.equals("p")||st1.equals("P"))
        {
            System.out.println(stu.s1+" is added present!");
        }
        else{System.out.println(stu.s1+" is added absent");}
   
        //s2
        System.out.print("Is "+stu.s2+" present? ");
        String st2 = sc.nextLine();
        if(st2.equals("p")||st2.equals("P"))
        {
            System.out.println(stu.s2+" is present!");
        }
        else{System.out.println(stu.s2+" is absent");}
        
        //s3
        System.out.print("Is "+stu.s3+" present? ");
        String st3 = sc.nextLine();
        if(st3.equals("p")||st3.equals("P"))
        {
            System.out.println(stu.s3+" is present!");
        }
        else{System.out.println(stu.s3+" is absent");}
        
        //s4        
        System.out.print("Is "+stu.s4+" present? ");
        String st4 = sc.nextLine();
        if(st4.equals("p")||st4.equals("P"))
        {
            System.out.println(stu.s4+" is present!");
        }
        else{System.out.println(stu.s4+" is absent");}
        
        //s5
        System.out.print("Is "+stu.s5+" present? ");
        String st5 = sc.nextLine();
        if(st5.equals("p")||st5.equals("P"))
        {
            System.out.println(stu.s5+" is present!");
        }
        else{System.out.println(stu.s5+" is absent");}
        
        //s6
        System.out.print("Is "+stu.s6+" present? ");
        String st6 = sc.nextLine();
        if(st6.equals("p")||st6.equals("P"))
        {
            System.out.println(stu.s6+" is present!");
        }
        else{System.out.println(stu.s6+" is absent");}

        //s7
        System.out.print("Is "+stu.s7+" present? ");
        String st7 = sc.nextLine();
        if(st7.equals("p")||st7.equals("P"))
        {
            System.out.println(stu.s7+" is present!");
        }
        else{System.out.println(stu.s7+" is absent");}
        
        //s8
        System.out.print("Is "+stu.s8+" present? ");
        String st8 = sc.nextLine();
        if(st8.equals("p")||st8.equals("P"))
        {
            System.out.println(stu.s8+" is present!");
        }
        else{System.out.println(stu.s8+" is absent");}
        
        //s9
        System.out.print("Is "+stu.s9+" present? ");
        String st9 = sc.nextLine();
        if(st9.equals("p")||st9.equals("P"))
        {
            System.out.println(stu.s9+" is present!");
        }
        else{System.out.println(stu.s9+" is absent");}
     
        sc.close();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: if you looking for I/O tutorial then check this https://dev.java/learn/java-io/

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how your program could look like. I put some comments in the code, so please take your time and understand how it works.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Attendance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // here you can specify all students you have
        List<String> students = List.of("Student 1", "Student 2", "Student R");
        System.out.println("This is an instruction.");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            Map<String, Boolean> attendance = new HashMap<>();
            for (String student : students) {
                System.out.println("Is " + student + " present? [P/n]");
                String answer = scanner.nextLine();
                attendance.put(student, "p".equalsIgnoreCase(answer));
            }
            // here you can specify path to output file
            // for Windows systems
            Path destinationFile = Paths.get("D:", "attendance_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");
            // for Unix systems
            // Path destinationFile = Paths.get("tmp", "attendance_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");

            // here is an output to file
            Files.writeString(destinationFile, attendance.toString(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to write file: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!